# Counting number of contiguous subarrays with positive sum in O(nlogn) using O(n) transformation

Tags: algorithm, arrays

I am interested in finding the number of contiguous sub-arrays that sum to a positive value (sum>0).

More formally, Given an array of integers A[1,...,n] I am looking to count the pairs of integers (i,j) such that 1<=i<=j<=n and A[i]+...+A[j]>0.

I am familiar with Kadane's algorithm for finding the maximum sum sub-array in O(n), and using a similar approach I can count the number of these sub-arrays in O(n^2).

To do this I take the cumulative sum T(i). I then compute T(j)-T(i-1) for all j=1,...,n and i=1,...,j and just record the differences that end up positive.

Apparently though there is an O(n) time routine that transforms this problem into a problem of counting the number of inversions (which can be achieved in O(nlogn) using say merge-sort). Try as I may though, I have been unable to find this transformation.

I do understand though that somehow I must match this inversion to the fact that the sum of elements between a pair (i,j) is positive.

Does anyone have any guidance as to how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am actually looking for the O(n) transformation rather than an alternative (not based on transformation plus inversion counting) solution to finding the number of sub arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the original array A, build another array sumA such that:

```
sumA[i] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[i].
```

Now in this sumA[] array if there are two indices i, j (i < j) such that sumA[i] < sumA[j],

Then `sumA[j] - sumA[i] > 0`. This is exactly the sum of all elements between indices i and j.

Hence the problem reduces to finding the number of inversions for the reverse of this array. This can be conducted by sorting the array sumA[] in descending order using mergesort and calculating the number of inversions encountered in this process.

Comment: I actually outline that idea in the question above. Unfortunately in this case the "transformation", i.e computing sumA[i] for all i, is O(n^2)

Comment: @Four_FUN No, it is O(n). It is the sum of all elements at positions less than i. sumA[0] = A[0]. sumA[i] = sumA[i-1] + A[i].

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Major mistake by me. Thank you very much kind sir! I can't up vote yet, but I ask anyone who can to do so! As always the solution was right in front of me!